# what is the difference between code and program?

Tags: coding-style

What is the difference between code and program?

In lexical terms

a code is the symbolic arrangement of data or instructions in a computer program or the set of such instructions

a program is a sequence of instructions that a computer can interpret and execute.

How different these are in the contextual terms.

For example, there exists some simulation codes, which are actually a set of programs.

What's the clue to interpret the factual meaning of a code and a program?

Comment: "Code" means "words and sentences", while "program" means the equivalent of "document" or "book" (or "chapter" if you will ;) ). Trying to define these things in any greater detail beyond that seems somewhat meaningless and sort of.. artificial (at least if you do not provide some more specific context to understand this in).

Answer (score 5):

In a compiled programming language the code gets compiled to the program (which is machine code)

In an interpreted script language the code is the program.

So, programs are always code, but code is not always a program.

Answer (score 2):

Code is the logic building language specific group of statements which on compilation produces a program. The program the compiled output which is an executable and is either platform specific or cross platform..